# How to perform rounding up or rounding down of a floating point number in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to round floating number in such a way that,

**If 7.4 comes, it should round to next lower number, that is 7.

If 7.5 or 7.6 comes it should round to next higher number, that is 8**

How can I do that? I am using python 2.7

Comment: Look at Python documentation for ceil and floor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `round()` function which comes builtin in python (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)

```
>>> round(7.4)
7
>>> round(7.5)
8
```

From the documentation:

> Note the behaviour of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for
>   example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected
>   `2.68`. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal
>   fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See [Floating Point
>   Arithmetic: Issues](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) and Limitations for more information.

Comment: Caveat: `round(8.5)` will give you a result of `9` in Python 2 and  `8` in Python 3. Keep this in mind if you ever want to switch to Python 3.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the [round() builtin](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round).

You haven't specified whether or not you are using Python 2 or 3, but note that in Python3, `round()` does bankers rounding: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round):

```
>>> round(7.4)
7
>>> round(7.5)
8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the round() method for this. The round() method takes two parameters. round(a, b). a is the the floating number whereas b is the number of decimal places up to which you want.

```
print round(60.23456, 2)
```

will give you an answer of 60.23

P.S This is python 2.7

In python 3 you can use

```
math.ceil(x) or math.floor(x)
```

for more information go to https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html

Hope this helps :)